Two points are selected randomly on a circle. What is the probability that central angle is $\theta$?
Two points are selected randomly on a circle. Connect the points to the center of the circle respectively and we can form a central angle.
Define $P(X=\theta)$ as the probability that the central angle $X$ is $\theta~rad$, we can have
\begin{equation}
P(X=\theta)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\pi} & \theta\in[0, \pi) \\
\frac{1}{2\pi} & \theta=\pi \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
What confuses me is when I integrate the equation, I would have
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{\pi}d\theta + \frac{1}{2\pi} > 1$$
What is the problem with my equation?

$P(X = \theta) = 0$
